# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'order_data'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        totalData=[]
        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(order_query)
                order_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_data = list(order_result)
                print(request.order_data)

                cursor.execute(order_detail_query)
                order_detail_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_detail_data = list(order_detail_result)
                print(request.order_detail_data)
            return Response({"order_data":order_result, "order_detail_data":order_detail_result},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        totalData.append({"order_data":order_data, "order_detail_data":order_detail_data})
        return Response({"totalData":totalData,})
```

> AttributeError at /api/order_list 'Request' object has no attribute
>   'order_data'

Comment: And your question is…?

Comment: @anonymoususer you are fetching order_data from the database and accessed from the request object so, the error is coming. You can simply `print(order_data)`. And also, you can use ORM instead of the raw query

Comment: Always, Happy Coding:) @anonymoususer

Comment: please take a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453324/python-how-to-get-inner-data-as-per-order-id). thank you! @MehaParekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add my comment as an answer.

you are fetching order_data from the database and accessed from the request object so, the error is coming. You can simply print

```
print(order_data)
```

And also, you can use ORM instead of the raw query doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/).