# Django: how to get order_detail_data as per order_id

Tags: python, mysql, django-rest-framework

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        totalData=[]
        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(order_query)
                order_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_data = list(order_result)
                # print(order_data)


                cursor.execute(order_detail_query)
                order_detail_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_detail_data = list(order_detail_result)
                # print(order_detail_data)

            totalData.append({"order_data":order_data, "order_detail_data":order_detail_data})
            return Response({"totalData":totalData,},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> output:

```
{
    "totalData": [
        {
            "order_data": [
                {
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "billing_shipping_id": 1,
                    "payment_method_id": 2,
                    "delivery_id": 2,
                    "txnid": "",
                    "order_no": "0822-1582695084-0006",
                    "delivery_amount": 0.0,
                    "discount_amount": 570.0,
                    "order_total": 2280.0,
                    "payment_status": "Unpaid",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "mihpayid": "",
                    "payuMoneyId": ""
                },    
            ],
           "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 1,
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "product_id": 202,
                    "product_size_id": 867,
                    "size_id": 1,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 2850.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "last_status_datatime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "feedback": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active"
                },
                ],
                },                                                                           
                ],                                                                              
                }
```

**what i want:**

> i want order_detail_data inside order_data as per order_id like this:

```
{
    "totalData": [
        {
            "order_data": [
                {
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "billing_shipping_id": 1,
                    "payment_method_id": 2,
                    "delivery_id": 2,
                    "txnid": "",
                    "order_no": "0822-1582695084-0006",
                    "delivery_amount": 0.0,
                    "discount_amount": 570.0,
                    "order_total": 2280.0,
                    "payment_status": "Unpaid",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "mihpayid": "",
                    "payuMoneyId": "",                                                          

                    "order_detail_data": [{                                              
                    "order_detail_id": 1,
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "product_id": 202,
                    "product_size_id": 867,
                    "size_id": 1,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 2850.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "last_status_datatime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "feedback": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active"                                                         
                      }],
                },
                   {                                                                    
                    "order_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "billing_shipping_id": 1,
                    "payment_method_id": 2,
                    "delivery_id": 2,
                    "txnid": "",
                    "order_no": "0822-1582695084-0007",
                    "delivery_amount": 0.0,
                    "discount_amount": 570.0,
                    "order_total": 2280.0,
                    "payment_status": "Unpaid",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "mihpayid": "",
                    "payuMoneyId": "",                                                          

                    "order_detail_data": [{                                              
                    "order_detail_id": 2,
                    "order_id": 2,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "product_id": 202,
                    "product_size_id": 867,
                    "size_id": 1,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 2850.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "last_status_datatime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "feedback": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active"                                                         

                    }], },    
                   # and so on...                                                     
                  ],
                },    
            ],
           "order_detail_data": [
                {
                    "order_detail_id": 1,
                    "order_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 5,
                    "product_id": 202,
                    "product_size_id": 867,
                    "size_id": 1,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "product_price": 2850.0,
                    "order_item_status": "Placed",
                    "last_status_datatime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "feedback": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2020-02-26T11:01:24",
                    "updated_datetime": "2020-02-26T05:31:24",
                    "status": "Active"
                },
                ],
                },                                                                            
                ],                                                                              
                }
```

> i am direct fetching data using raw query from
>   databases instead of ORM. i want to get order_detail_data inside order_data as per
>   order_id.

**i am trying to solve this problem, but i didn't get any possible answer which could solve this problem. It would be great if anyone could help me out for what i am looking for. Advance thank you so much!**.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort toward solving this yourself?

Comment: @anonymoususer you can just review your code again, you can solve it by yourself, It is very easy, Try this otherwise we are here to help you if you can't able to do it!

Comment: Can you add your model to the post?.

Comment: i do not have any model cause i am using raw query instead of ORM @cabesuon

Comment: did you found any solution? @MehaParekh

Comment: Did you try anyting? @anonymoususer

Comment: take a look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501400/python-django-i-am-trying-to-solve-below-question) @MehaParekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using raw queries, then you just need to merge the data. Something like this should work,

```
def merge_order_data_and_detail(orders, details):
  """Group details by order_id and merge it in orders."""
  # create dictionary key:order_id value:[order_detail_data]
  dic = {}
  for d in details:
    if d['order_id'] not in dic:
      dic[d['order_id']] = []
    dic[d['order_id']].append(d)
  # iterate orders and add details
  for o in orders:
    if o['order_id'] in dic:
      o['order_detail_data'] = dic[o['order_id']]

orders = [
  {
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 5
  },
  {
      "order_id": 2,
      "user_id": 50
  }    
]
details = [
  {
      "order_detail_id": 1,
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 5,
      "product_id": 202
  },
  {
      "order_detail_id": 2,
      "order_id": 1,
      "user_id": 5,
      "product_id": 203
  },
  {
      "order_detail_id": 3,
      "order_id": 2,
      "user_id": 50,
      "product_id": 402
  },
  {
      "order_detail_id": 4,
      "order_id": 2,
      "user_id": 50,
      "product_id": 403
  }
]
merge_order_data_and_detail(orders, details)
print(orders)
```

Result:

```
[{'order_id': 1, 'user_id': 5, 'order_detail_data': [{'order_detail_id': 1, 'order_id': 1, 'user_id': 5, 'product_id': 202}, {'order_detail_id': 2, 'order_id': 1, 'user_id': 5, 'product_id': 203}]}, {'order_id': 2, 'user_id': 50, 'order_detail_data': [{'order_detail_id': 3, 'order_id': 2, 'user_id': 50, 'product_id': 402}, {'order_detail_id': 4, 'order_id': 
2, 'user_id': 50, 'product_id': 403}]}]
```

I remove a lot of orders and details attributes just to make simple to test.

I don't have the whole picture, but should think in using Django models if you are not already using it. It is the way to take advantage of the full potential of the framework.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is your input data?

Comment: the expected output that you mention in the link is the result of the function of the answer, you are just missing a name attribute for the details, you can't have a value without a key in a dictionary .. what is that I am missing from the expected result?

Comment: thank you so much. i really much appreciated! @cabesuon

Comment: glad it help you!